# Business Objects Infoview - Export to Excel doesn't correctly autosize cell height

Tags: reporting, business-objects, infoview

I have a large quantity of data from Remedy that I am using in a Business Objects InfoView/Webi report. The report is exported to Excel for distribution to department management.

I have all the formatting set up in InfoView so that nothing needs to be done in Excel before sending the report off to the powers that be. I have all the table cells set to autosize except one column, due to how long it can get (the notes field in Remedy, which is a blob data type). I do, however, have that set to autoheight.

When exporting to Excel, the autosize isn't quite right - it cuts the cell off by about two lines of text. What can I do to make this behave in the export?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found with business objects (I assume you mean version XI) that all excel formatted distributed reports lose their formatting during conversion.  I have had the very same problem, both with sizing of a couple of fields and a calculation field of average that would not keep it's number format after the excel change.  It became general again.  I also researched this and found this link to the issue:  http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.csdw.status.dhhs.state.nc.us/BOXIUserGuides/user.pdf&sa=U&ei=1xl-UKTuCMbg2QXd1IHABw&ved=0CC0QFjAJ&usg=AFQjCNHVTN7vKzYNUMDID0mqCvOenfhkJw

That is to the guide.

Here is the passage:  The difference between Excel and Excel (Data only) is that Excel
attempts to *preserve* the look and feel of your original report, while Excel
(Data only) saves only the data, with each cell representing a field.

I found on some other website that while it attempts to preserve it, some or all formatting may be lost.